# CURL in PHP chroot'ed environment

Tags: php, curl, chroot

How can I find out what files or sockets are needed by Curl when running in a chroot'ed PHP environment on Mac OSX?

I recently secured my website by chrooting PHP but now every call to Amazon S3 through it's API is failing, with the error message:

```
Resource id #43; cURL error: Couldn't resolve host 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

The same code works fine when called from a non-chroot`ed command line so presumably it's some set of files that need to be opened by CURL that are failing to be opened.

How do I figure out which files it's trying to open to be able to map them into the chroot'ed directoy?

With Andrei's suggestion I used strace (or rather dtruss the mac equivalent) to get some debug output.

This is a request that is chrooted and doesn't work.

```
lstat64("/lib/amazonWS/lib\0", 0x7FFF5FBF97D0, 0x26)         = 0 0
lstat64("/lib/amazonWS\0", 0x7FFF5FBF9630, 0x182)        = 0 0
open("/lib/amazonWS/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F448, 0x8)       = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F448, 0x90)      = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F448, 0x1001B1FE4)       = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x72D1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5, 0xFFFFFF8016E89160)         = 0x3BF0000 0
stat64("/lib/amazonWS/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php\0", 0x10621CD68, 0x10621C847)        = 0 0
munmap(0x103BF0000, 0x72D1)      = 0 0
close(0x5)       = 0 0
setitimer(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFBCE0, 0x0)      = 0 0
kqueue(0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x0, 0x50)        = 5 0
kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x1)         = 0 0
socket(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)        = 6 0
setsockopt(0x6, 0xFFFF, 0x1022)      = 0 0
connect_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFADD0, 0x6A)      = -1 Err#2
close_nocancel(0x6)      = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
kqueue(0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x0, 0x50)        = 5 0
kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x1)         = 0 0
socket(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)        = 6 0
setsockopt(0x6, 0xFFFF, 0x1022)      = 0 0
connect_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFADD0, 0x6A)      = -1 Err#2
close_nocancel(0x6)      = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFBA80, 0x0)        = 0 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x5, 0x32, 0x7FFF5FBFBCB0)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/basereality\0", 0x7FFF5FBFB9F0, 0x0)        = 0 0
lstat64("/basereality/../BaseReality/html/50x.html\0", 0x7FFF5FBFB730, 0x23D)        = 0 0
```

This is a request that is *not* chrooted and works:

```
 1806/0x1dd3:    149524       5      3 open("/documents/projects/intahwebz/intahwebz/lib/amazonWS/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = 5 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149525       3      0 fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F578, 0x8)        = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149527       2      0 fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F578, 0x90)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149528       2      0 fstat64(0x5, 0x100A9F578, 0x1001B1FE4)        = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149531       5      2 mmap(0x0, 0x72D1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5, 0x1F)        = 0x3BF0000 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149535       4      2 stat64("/documents/projects/intahwebz/intahwebz/lib/amazonWS/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php\0", 0x1061966D0, 0x106196057)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149565       6      3 munmap(0x103BF0000, 0x72D1)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149568       4      2 close(0x5)        = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149661       4      1 setitimer(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFBCE0, 0x0)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149767      90      2 kqueue(0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x0, 0x50)         = 5 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149770       4      1 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149782      12      8 socketpair(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149792      12      9 sendto_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FCF0, 0x3A)       = 58 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149796       7      3 sendmsg_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAD30, 0x0)        = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149797       4      0 close_nocancel(0x9)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149802      45      4 recvfrom_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFAD7C, 0x4)       = 4 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149806       5      2 close_nocancel(0x7)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149814       6      3 socketpair(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149816       4      1 sendto_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FCF0, 0x3A)       = 58 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149818       5      2 sendmsg_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAD30, 0x0)        = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149819       3      0 close_nocancel(0x9)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149822     215      2 recvfrom_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFAD7C, 0x4)       = 4 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149840      20     17 close_nocancel(0x7)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149843       4      1 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB000, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149844       3      1 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149846       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149848       5      2 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149851       5      1 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FCF0, 0x40)         = 64 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149856       8      3 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149861       3      1 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149863       4      1 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149864       3      1 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D85990, 0x42)         = 66 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149867       4      1 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149869       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149871       3      1 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149872       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149873       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149874       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149876       4      1 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149877       4      0 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D859E0, 0x40)         = 64 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149879       3      1 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149881       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149883       3      0 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149884       3      0 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D85A20, 0x42)         = 66 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149886       3      1 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149888       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149889       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149890       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149900  389953      9 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149904      60      1 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149909       7      3 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149913       7      2 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FD10, 0x2E)         = 46 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149921       9      4 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149928       5      1 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149932       3      1 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149932       2      0 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149945  439745     12 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149952      13      3 kevent(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)         = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149961      15      6 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFAE30, 0x1C)      = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149969      11      4 recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FD10, 0x2A)         = 42 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149981      16      8 select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFADB0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    149987       9      3 kevent(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFA860, 0x1)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150002      19      9 sendto_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FCF0, 0x1C)       = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150011      12      5 sendto_nocancel(0x6, 0x105D8FCF0, 0x1C)       = 28 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150025      22     10 close_nocancel(0x5)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150095      26     18 socket(0x2, 0x1, 0x6)         = 5 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150109      12      4 setsockopt(0x5, 0xFFFF, 0x1022)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150113       9      2 fcntl(0x5, 0x3, 0x0)      = 2 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150117       7      2 fcntl(0x5, 0x4, 0x6)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150191      81     73 connect(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB9F0, 0x10)        = -1 Err#36
 1806/0x1dd3:    150217  689426     21 select(0x6, 0x7FFF5FBFB730, 0x7FFF5FBFB6B0, 0x7FFF5FBFB630, 0x7FFF5FBFB7D0)       = 1 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150226      72      2 getsockopt(0x5, 0xFFFF, 0x1007)       = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150230       6      2 getpeername(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB780, 0x7FFF5FBFB6FC)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150232       4      1 getsockname(0x5, 0x7FFF5FBFB700, 0x7FFF5FBFB6FC)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150332      23     17 open_nocancel("/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = 7 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150339       6      2 fstat64(0x7, 0x7FFF5FBFB440, 0x7FFF5FBFB50C)      = 0 0
 1806/0x1dd3:    150350      14      9 read_nocancel(0x7, "##\n## lib/ca-bundle.crt -- Bundle of CA Root Certificates\n##\n## Certificate data from Mozilla as of: Thu Nov 22 00:12:21 2012\n##\n## This is a bundle of X.509 certificates of public Certificate Authorities\n## (CA). These were automatically extracted from Mo", 0x1000)      = 4096 0
```

So it looks like it isn't a direct file access that's failing in the process but socket send. I'm following some instructions to try set up /dev/urandom and other non-file paths into the chrooted environment, but again, is there any way to know what socket `socketpair(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)` is rather than just working in the dark?

**Update 2**

It's a known problem on OSX to do a DNS lookup inside a chroot:
https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2011-April/014565.html

Apparently I need to run a mDNSResponder service at /path/to/chroot/var/run/mDNSResponder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently on OSX all system calls to `gethostbyname` are directed through the mDNSResponder service which is running as a socket at /var/run/mDNSResponder which is different from Linux platforms where DNS requests are just sent through files such as resolv.conf.

mDNSResponder is not available in the chroot'ed environment and so all DNS lookups will fail.

Theoretically it's possible to create a duplicate mDNSResponder service that is listening on a socket at /chroot/var/run/mDNSResponder. However no-one appears to have actually done this.

What is much easier to do is to set up a proxy service e.g. with [Squidman](http://squidman.net/squidman/) running on the localhost and then make all HTTP requests through it.

Also to note creating your own dev/random and dev/urandom inside the chroot with `mknod` doesn't appear to work as they run out of randomness, and the proxy requests will fail. Instead you should link them with `sudo ln -s /dev/urandom /chroot/dev/urandom`

Answer (score 2):

Probably there are DNS issue, check if there are correct resolv.conf under your chroot environment.

Comment: Yes, I've mapped `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/home/projectname/etc/resolv.conf` but still get the error. So how do I track what files it's trying to access?

Comment: You can try to debug this with strace command and find which files are accessed.